# Choosing lines with GAWK

Tags: bash, shell, gawk

I have a file with data:

```
 /homes/XXXX/YYYYY/file1:20150324
 /homes/XXXX/YYYYY/file2:20150327
 /homes/XXXX/YYYYY/file3:20150320
 /homes/XXXX/YYYYY/file3:20150327
 /homes/XXXX/YYYYY/file4:20150328
```

First field is path, `:` as a separator and second field is a date. What I want to do is to select only those lines with date lower then some value.

`gawk -v var="$SOMEVALUE" '{FS = ":"; if($2<=var) print;}'`

This is what I have. It works fine, prints lines with lower value than I want to, but it everytime prints also the first line, no matter the value. Could you give me some advice what to do? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
gawk -F: -v var="$SOMEVALUE" 'var>=$2'
```

The error is that you had to change the field separator after you read the first row.

Comment: The default action in awk is `{print}` so you can remove that.

Answer (score 0):

@JuniorCompressor
I didn't realise that. Will save me trouble in future scripts. Thanks :-)

@sykatch
You could also statically define the field separator within your gawk script like:

```
    gawk -v var="20150323" 'BEGIN {FS = ":"}; {if($2<=var) print;}' datefile.txt
```

but the solution suggested by JuniorCompressor is more flexible.